# Are thermal reliefs on SMD pads beneficial when reflow soldering?

Tags: soldering, surface-mount, reflow

I know that thermal reliefs have benefits when hand-soldering through-hole components.

For some high-frequency or high-current components, I understand why it's a good idea not to use thermal reliefs.

Is it a good practice to use thermal reliefs by default for all other SMD components?

How do they affect reflow soldering?

Answer (score 3):

For small components, 0603, 0402 and smaller, tombstone is a problem (One side of the component rises upwards due to temperature gradient), and a thermal relief can solve it.